# Simple tab question

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically using tab character in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686536/programmatically-using-tab-character-in-net)

Is there an equivalent value for "\t" as System.Environment.NewLine is to "\r\n"?

I am looking for something built into the framework.  I know it is a trivial question, but I couldn't find anything during my googling session.  I am hoping/wishing this exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686536/programmatically-using-tab-character-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newline varies from platform to platform but tab does no, so it should be safe to use `"\t"` . I guess you could create a const and use it for sanity.

Comment: Yes, unix/linux use the "\n" only without the return char, while windows uses the "\r\n".  I was curious if a predefined constant existed in the framework.  Thanks